# How do i request persistant storage quota from dart?

Tags: html, dart, html5-filesystem

I'm creating my persistent html5 filesystem storage like this from dart:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(Window.PERSISTENT, 
       5 * 1024 * 1024, onFSOpened, onFSError);
```

Any operation on the filesystem fails with the error QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR.  However, it works with TEMPORARY.

A reply in this [thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85000) suggests that for persistent storage, I should request quota manually with this JavaScript API

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota
```

I don't find window.webkitStorageInfo in dart (checked with latest build).   Any pointers?

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` returns successfully.  However, any write operations on the filesystem throws an Quota Exceeded error

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this line on build 9797 using Dartium, and it worked for me:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(Window.PERSISTENT, 
    5 * 1024 * 1024, (f) => print('got it'));
```

Comment: John, thanks for the reply.   If you try to create anything with that file system object, (e.g. a directory or a file), it would throw a Quota exceeded error.   By default, persistent mode returns with 0 byte quota and has to be explicitly requested. I don't find this API in dart to request the quota

Comment: hmm, I'll check it out again tomorrow and at least help validate it for you.  Probably wouldn't hurt to open a bug at http://www.dartbug.com/new

Comment: Yep. I'm getting the same result as you.

Comment: John, thanks for confirming.  Looks like a bug.   I've filed a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4175)